# I would like to fill characters in an image with solid black

Tags: gimp, fill

I have an image that contains a few [image: Sample characters] characters that are currently various shades of gradient gray.  They start out dark on one edge and the rest of the character is a gradient of grays.  Each successive letter is a bit lighter than the one next to it.  I think I was able to outline the characters using edge detect and was trying to figure out how to do a color fill into the characters but I'm missing how to select only the characters that are in enclosed in the edges.  So if that's the wrong way to do it, let me know what I'm missing.  I know I can do a freestyle select but that would be painful and I'm not much of an artist so it would look horrible.
Thanks,
Jim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use levels or curves. (Menu > Color > Curves...)

Locate the part that represents your black text.

[image]

And move the curves to the floor = Black.

[image]

You can additionally make the paper white.

---

Using Levels is the same. You locate the hump that represents the tones of your text and move the small triangle.

[image]

If you move the white triangle you will make your paper white.

---

To remove the yellow tint, you can desaturate the image. (Menu > Colors > Saturation)

Comment: That worked great, thank you.